# Does CloudPanel support apache server?

Tags: apache, digital-ocean

I'm trying to host multiple website with CloudPanel with only one DigitalOcean Droplet. In CloudPanel, I can't find Apache Server.

I searched for documentation or smth related to CloudPanel. Is there a good documentation or explaination?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

CloudPanel does not run on Apache. It is based on Nginx.

Answer (score -2):

No, CloudPanel itself doesn't directly support Apache as the web server.
CloudPanel is designed to work with Nginx

It's important to note that Nginx is generally considered faster and more efficient than Apache, especially for handling high-traffic websites. This is one of the reasons CloudPanel uses Nginx by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).